# How to Effectively Reverse Windows Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

A couple years ago, I built a computer for my father. His PC has an SSD + 2 TB hard drive setup. Earlier this year, we added an additional 2 TB hard drive to his tower. For awhile all was well, but my dad is NOT very computer savvy and kept confusing where his data was stored (and where TO store his data). So, I tried turning on Windows Storage Spaces for him, as it obfuscates away multiple drives to where it appears as simply one big drive on the Windows file system. However, while going through the prompts and setting this up, Microsoft makes NO ATTEMPT anywhere on the text prompts to advise the user that it will perform a quick format... In retrospective, I suppose I should've expected that. Once I finished setting up Storage Spaces a quick format immediately went through and it showed 4 TB of empty drive space...

In a bit of a panic, I immediately tried to reverse this, as I didn't want my dad to lose any of his important data he's compiled over the last 2 decades of our lives! However, ever since removing the drives off of Storage Spaces now only 1 of the drives is able to be recognized by Windows, which is making it very difficult to properly recover any data. It seems that Windows writes a bunch of metadata to abstract away visible partitions into one. The hard drives in question here are:

- Seagate 2TB HDD - Model ST2000DM001-1ER164
- Western Digital 2TB HDD - Model WD2003FZEX-00SRLA0
- I've also been using my personal Seagate Backup Plus 2TB (SRD00F1) to try and recover files from his internal drives onto this with EaseUS software.

I've tried various utilities and software to attempt recovery of my dad's data. I know the data is still there because a quick format as carried out by Storage Spaces does not destroy any data, but allows the user to start overwriting previously written disk data. Programs I've used so far are:

- Acronis Disk Director 12.5
- EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard
- SeaTools for Windows
- Seagate DiscWizard
- Recuva
- Unformat (from LSoft, Unformat.com) [currently trying]

The 2 problems I keep running into is that not all of the drives can ever be read and understood by Windows all at the same time, and that of course most of the data on these drives is still missing as it's displayed on Windows Explorer. I've Googled for hours and have attempted a bunch of different solutions, all to not much results. Now, I must tap the brilliance of StackExchange for some direction...

Various representations of the drives in their current state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x4OT.jpg

Does anyone have any direction or suggestions for me on this? I'm at a point where I might start getting quotes from data recovery services.. which I really don't want to do. The data is there, just all jumbled up!

Comment: I would start to perform research on data recovery firms. The most you attempt by yourself, using the wrong tools for the job, the more likely data recovery will be impossible.  I don't make this recommendation lightly, it will come at a cost, ultimately only you can determine if it's worth the costs to "maybe" recover something.  One program you have not attempted is [Test Disk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which you could try, provided you understand the risks of attempting to recover data yourself.

Comment: Try also [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to come full-circle on this, my dad and I ended up paying for data recovery from [OnTrack](https://www.ontrack.com/). It costed us $900 back then for them to recover data off of the two 2TB hard disk drives.

The whole process took 2-weeks, once you pay them they ship to you packaging and shipping instructions for your applicable drives. After they receive your drives they then email you their analysis results, and promptly ship back your original drives plus an additional drive that has all your recovered data on it.

They were able to recover 100% of the missing data for us that Windows Storage Spaces had quick-formatted.

Big learning experience for me, - now I know anytime anything is changed as far as drive partitioning goes, guarantee there will be formatting of your drives occurring.